# Object in vuex lose parameters

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

SystemStack.ts

```
import { PianoMenu, DEFAULT_MENU } from "@/core/ui/menu/PianoMenu";

export interface SystemStack {
  piano: PianoMenu;
  startWork: Date;
}

export class DefaultSystemStack implements SystemStack {
  piano: PianoMenu = DEFAULT_MENU;
  startWork: Date = new Date();
}
```

This is system information.

Stack storage

```
import { Module } from "vuex";
import { RootState } from "@/core/store/Types";
import { SystemStack, DefaultSystemStack } from "@/core/system/SystemStack";
import { getters } from "./getters";
import { actions } from "./actions";
import { mutations } from "./mutations";

export const state: SystemStack = new DefaultSystemStack();

const namespaced = true;

export const systemStack: Module<SystemStack, RootState> = {
  namespaced,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

Stack storage. Actions

```
import { ActionTree } from "vuex";
import { RootState } from "@/core/store/Types";
import { SystemStack } from "@/core/system/SystemStack";
import { MenuGroup } from "@/core/ui/menu/PianoMenu";

export const actions: ActionTree<SystemStack, RootState> = {
  initSystemStack({ commit }, newStack: SystemStack): any {
    commit("initializeSystemStack", newStack);
  },
  addMenuGroup({ commit }, menuGroup: MenuGroup): any {
    commit("configStackAddMenuGroup", menuGroup);
  }
};
```

Stack storage. Mutations

```
import { SystemStack } from "@/core/system/SystemStack";
import { MenuGroup } from "@/core/ui/menu/PianoMenu";

export const mutations: MutationTree<SystemStack> = {
  initializeSystemStack(state, newStack: SystemStack) {
    state = newStack;
  },
  configStackAddMenuGroup(state, menuGroup: MenuGroup) {
    state.piano.addGroup(menuGroup);
  }
};
```

In `App.vue` I used method `mounted`. In the method, I initialize the stack and add my menu items.

```
export default class App extends Vue {
  @ProcessAction executeProcess: any;
  @SystemStackAction addMenuGroup: any;
  @SystemStackAction initSystemStack: any;
  @JournalAction addInfoEvent?: any;

  drawer = true;
  menu = false;
  empty = [0];

  mounted() {
      this.initSystemStack(new DefaultSystemStack());
      this.addMenuGroup(GROUP_CUSTOM_MENU);
  }
}
```

And now, after the initialization of the stack, I have a default stack with the default menu, but if I try to add new menu items, I get an `undefined` value, because the stack does not have the `piano` parameter in the store. I watched `piano` after the stack was initialized, and this parameter was. Help me to understand filled

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I'm trying to redefine state. This is unacceptable. I can change parameters of state. I think that this behavior is described somewhere in the documentation, it will be necessary to find, if I find I will insert a link